# Fill in text field with value from select list in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am trying to build a form to register a car at a dealership for payments and there is a select list that lets you pick a month from the `Months` table. The `Months` table also has a column for the `number of weeks` per month. I want to have the ability to select a month from the select box and based on the month, the `number of weeks` should populate the `number of` weeks` textfield. Is there any way that this may be possible?

Razor Page:

```
<MudSelect @bind-Value="car.Month" For="@(()=>car.Month)" T="int" Label="Month" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" Required="true">
    @foreach (var item in num)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="@item.Month">@item.Month</MudSelectItem>
    }  
</MudSelect>

<MudTextField Label="Current year number of weeks" Clearable Required HelperText="" Class="mt-3"
              @bind-Value="car.numberOfWeeks" For="@(() => car.numberOfWeeks)" /> //currently it is an input field

@code{
    NumberOfWeeks nums = new NumberOfWeeks();
    private List<NumberOfWeeks> num = new List<NumberOfWeeks>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        GetNumberOfWeeks();  
    }

    private List<NumberOfWeeks> GetNumberOfWeeks()
    {
        num=carService.GetNumberOfWeeks();
        return num;
    }
}
```

CarService.cs:

```
public List<NumberOfWeeks> GetNumberOfWeeks()
{
    return _dbContext.NumberOfWeeks.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is a very similar question to this one you posted earlier today - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73470739/getting-values-from-table-in-a-select-box-in-blazor/73475770#73475770.  It's courteous to response to answers to questions already posted before posting more of a very similar nature.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, those are different questions though? this one is if its possible to change a text field value to a column value of a table if a value is selected from the drop down. The one you have referenced is pulling table values into a dropdown...

Comment: Make sure that OnChange of the select, a method will be called. This method will take the car.Months value, and convert it to weeks, and then save it to weeks field. After which StateHasChanged() can be called, which should update the textfield, since it's already using a binding to the property.

Comment: @IAmDrNoLIfe, The `numberofweeks` field is already populated in my table. How would I go about doing that? :(

Comment: Your "num" field contains a list of number of weeks. I suppose this is equivalent to January -> 12 months (left of the year), etc. Furthermore from your question it seems like you want your textfield to be populated with the correct amount of weeks, based on the month.
So register a method to the select's OnChange event. Have this method figure out what  month is currently selected (jan, feb, etc..) and then populate the field that is bound to the week text field, and then call StateHasChanged.

Comment: I can't see it in the code, but you also need to have somewhere to store the selected week and the week value you want to display. This can just be a field in your .cs This is the field you want to databind to your textfield.

Comment: @IAmDrNoLIfe, I sort of understand what you mean, but I am still really confused... my apologies for being a noob, it is my first time doing this :(

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, then this gist should be what you're looking for. https://gist.github.com/DrNoLife/824d0f85bd404460e151d48d21317ebd

It is of course extremely simple, meaning I hardcoded the values and whatnot. But the general way of getting to the end should be clear from it.

Comment: @IAmDrNoLIfe This is what I am looking for, however, when I use IndexOf, I get a cannot convert to int error in the code... do you know why that is?

Comment: You need to make sure the datatypes you are using are the correct ones. C# is statically typed, meaning the datatype has meaning. If you have an object containing a bunch of information, you can't just convert that object into an int (or a string to an int, same issue). 

So just check your code, and make sure the datatypes are matching up.

Comment: @IAmDrNoLIfe Okay, I think I fixed it, but it shows 0 in the text field, regardless of the selection 

`private async Task HandleSelectChange(ChangeEventArgs args) { int selectedMonth = (int)args.Value;
        // Get index from months.
        int monthIndex = num.IndexOf(nums, selectedMonth);
        // NumberOfWeeks handling.
        var numWeeks = num[monthIndex];
        nums.CynumberOfWeeks = numWeeks.CynumberOfWeeks;
        StateHasChanged();}`

Comment: Then you can make use of debugging to get the final answer.
Create a breakpoint in your code, and go through it with the debugging tool, line by line, and see what objects you are retrieving, and what values those objects might have.

It's an essential part of developing, hence why I'm mentioning it.